# How to permanently configure gradle path

Tags: linux, centos, path

Good day,

I have a linux environment and its installed with gradle 4.7 long time ago. when I echo $PATH, I can see `:/opt/gradle/gradle-4.7/bin` inside. However, I am not sure how previous person configure this inside.

I download the latest gradle 6.8.3 and unzip it in another folder, which is /home/meow/Workspaces/g/gradle/gradle-6.8.3.

Base on gradle website, I can manually use the following command to configure my latest gradle path:
`$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/meow/Workspaces/g/gradle/gradle-6.8.3/bin`

But this is only within the session. When I go to another terminal and type gradle -v, its still showing version 4.7.

The previous owner of this environment already resign, thus I have no idea how he configure last time.

My question are:

1. How/where to configure the gradle path for version 4.7 last time?
2. How can I change the gradle path to 6.8.3

The OS is CentOs Linux.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PATH` variable is set in the startup files for your shell (`echo $SHELL`). I'll assume `bash` hereafter. Read `man bash`.

Look for assignments to `PATH` in `$HOME/.bashrc`, and in any files `source`d from `$HOME/.bashrc` (`source` is sometimes typed as "`.`"), and in the system's shell startup files.

```
grep -E 'PATH=|^[[:space:]]*source|^[[:space:]]*\.' $HOME/.bash* $HOME/.profile /etc/bash* /etc/profile
```

will get you started.

Comment: Thanks. Found it on my .bash_profile

Comment: I need to restart after I configure on it in order to take effect?

Comment: After you edit your `.bashrc`, you may reapply it to the current shell with `source $HOME/.bashrc`.